# Styling last menu item on multilevel menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to stylize the last menu choice on a menu that has dropdowns in it.
This is kind of what it looks like.  The > means it's a drop down.

Home   AAA>  BBB>  CCC   DDD  Contact Donate

I'm trying to make JUST the Donate choice have a red background with white letters, so I've put this in:

```
#main-nav  li:last-child a { 
   color:#ffffff; 
   background-color:rgb(178, 45, 58); 
   border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
   padding: 5px;
}
```

But that is making the last item in each of the dropdowns red too!

How can I make just the last item of the main menu be stylized?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share you HTML mark up? it will make answering this a lot easier if we can understand what you have already.

Comment: Let's see if this helps:

Comment: Oops...@ether The code is too long for here apparently.  But I uploaded it so it can be seen at <www.bcp-design.com/overflow/awfulcode.rtf>  and there is an image there so you can see what's happening <www.bcp-design.com/overflow/menuimage.png>       The above css is what I was trying and when I changed it to #main-nav > ul > li:last-child > a as suggested below, none of the css formatting was applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post this, but please accept Chris' answer as his is right, except he did not have the correct `Id` name for the navigation.

```
#navigation > ul > li:last-child > a{
    color:Red;
}
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvwoLc99/)** demonstrating that the 'Donate' is the only thing being turned `red`.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the immediate children of the navigation list. Use this selector:

`#main-nav > ul > li:last-child > a`

Comment: that actually didn't work.  There were no changes to the menu item now.